# Storing nodelist values in a variable before HTML is changed by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Please excuse my poor coding, this is my first time using JavaScript. Here is a CodePen: https://codepen.io/lachlaneditswikis/pen/VVgGPW?editors=0011

I would like to store the original values from the HTML, so I can convert the units from feet to metres and vice versa, without the loss in accuracy that occurs from rounding the output. I found that despite converting the nodelist to an array and saving it as a variable, it still changes to the converted value.

Thanks

I've attempted to reduce the code a bit, however I think the problem is related to the cookie so I've left that in.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("bodyContent");
var lengthString = document.querySelectorAll(".convertable-length");
var lengthStringOriginal = lengthString;
window.addEventListener('load', switchUnits());

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function switchUnits() {
  var preference = document.getElementById("unitSelect").value;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < lengthString.length; i++) {
    var l = lengthStringOriginal[i].innerHTML;
    var lStripped = l.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    if (preference == "metric") {
        if (l.includes('feet') || l.includes('foot')) {
          lengthString[i].innerHTML = Math.round(lStripped * 0.3048) + " meters";
        }
    }
    if (preference == "imperial") {
      if (l.includes('meter') || l.includes('metre')) {
          lengthString[i].innerHTML = lStripped * 3.2808399 + " feet";
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="bodyContent">
  <select id="unitSelect" onchange="switchUnits()"> 
    <option value="default">Default</option>
    <option value="metric">Metric</option>
    <option value="imperial">Imperial</option>
  </select>
  <ul>
    <li class="convertable-length">100 feet</li>
    <li class="convertable-length">100 meters</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry it's my first time using this website as well, been a longtime reader but never asked before. Unfortunately the whole code is based on the cookie. The cookie is either "default", "imperial" or "metric". Default leaves values how they are, whereas imperial and metric converts them. My problem is, if I convert from one to the other and back again, the values do not match. I am trying to save a copy of all the span elements, so that I can convert according to the original value, not the value that was edited by JavaScript. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: OK, the code is now functional, basically because I defined the lengthStringOriginal variable at the start, I expected that to contain the original HTML contents (100 feet). I am trying to keep that the same, so that I can always convert accurately by referring to this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saving a static `NodeList`, but the `NodeList` contains **mutable** objects, not copies of them. Exactly like this:

```js
const a = [
  {value: 1}
];
const b = a.slice();
console.log(a[0].value); // 1
console.log(b[0].value); // 1
a[0].value = 2;
console.log(a[0].value); // 2
console.log(b[0].value); // 2
```

If you want to save the original *content* of those DOM elements, save their `innerHTML` rather than saving the elements themselves:

```
var lengthString = x.querySelectorAll(".convertable-length");
var lengthStringOriginal = Array.prototype.map.call(
    lengthString,
    function(element) {
        return element.innerHTML;
    }
);
```

Then in your conversion function:

```
var l = lengthStringOriginal[i];
```

(Instead of `.innerHTML` on the end.)

Also note that

```
window.addEventListener('load', switchUnits());
```

should be

```
window.addEventListener('load', switchUnits);
// No parens ------------------------------^
```

if you want to call `switchUnits` in response to the `load` event. (The `()` **call** it and pass its return value in to `addEventListener` instead.)

Here it is with those changes made. I think there are other issues to resolve, but this solves the problem you asked about:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("bodyContent");
var lengthString = x.getElementsByClassName("convertable-length");
var lengthStringOriginal = Array.prototype.map.call(
    lengthString,
    function(element) {
        return element.innerHTML;
    }
);
window.addEventListener('load', switchUnits);

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function switchUnits() {
  var preference = document.getElementById("unitSelect").value;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < lengthString.length; i++) {
    var l = lengthStringOriginal[i]; // ***
    var lStripped = l.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    if (preference == "metric") {
        if (l.includes('feet') || l.includes('foot')) {
          lengthString[i].innerHTML = Math.round(lStripped * 0.3048) + " meters";
        }
    }
    if (preference == "imperial") {
      if (l.includes('meter') || l.includes('metre')) {
          lengthString[i].innerHTML = lStripped * 3.2808399 + " feet";
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="bodyContent">
  <select id="unitSelect" onchange="switchUnits()"> 
    <option value="default">Default</option>
    <option value="metric">Metric</option>
    <option value="imperial">Imperial</option>
  </select>
  <ul>
    <li class="convertable-length">100 feet</li>
    <li class="convertable-length">100 meters</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```